# Unable to open SO screen SO301000 using Action from Quote screen CR304500

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a Action called CREATE SO in Sales Quote screen to create Sales order.
I am unable to open the sales order screen using this action. though the sales order is getting created
but the SO screen is not opening while creating the SO. I am not sure where i am making mistake in  my code. Please suggest. Thanks.

```
      #region Create Sales Order

        public PXAction<CRQuote> createSalesOrder;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create SO", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXProcessButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        public IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            QuoteMaint graphObject = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();

            foreach (CRQuote quote in adapter.Get())
            {
                //Create resultset for Quote Details
                PXResultset<CROpportunityProducts> PXSetLine = PXSelect<CROpportunityProducts,
                Where<CROpportunityProducts.quoteID,
                Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.quoteID>>>>.Select(this.Base, quote.QuoteID);
                List<CROpportunityProducts> QuoteList = new List<CROpportunityProducts>();
                foreach (CROpportunityProducts line in PXSetLine)
                {
                    QuoteList.Add(line);
                }
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () => CreateSalesOrderMethod(quote, QuoteList));
                
                yield return quote;
            }
        }

        //Private Method for Create Sales Order
        public virtual void CreateSalesOrderMethod(CRQuote quote, List<CROpportunityProducts> QuoteList)
        {
            //Base.Save.Press();
            bool var_orderCreated = false;
            bool erroroccured = false;
            string ErrMsg = "";

            SOOrderEntry orderGraphObjet = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            SOOrder orderHeaderObject = new SOOrder();
            QuoteMaint currGRPH = PXGraph.CreateInstance<QuoteMaint>();
                        
                BAccount customer = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<CRQuote.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base, quote.BAccountID);
                if (customer.Type == "CU")
                {
                    orderHeaderObject.CustomerID = quote.BAccountID;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new PXException("Business Account not converted to Customer yet"); // THIS ERROR IS ALSO NOT SHOWING WHILE ENCOUNTERING.
                }
                orderHeaderObject.CuryOrderTotal = quote.CuryProductsAmount;
                orderHeaderObject.CuryTaxTotal = quote.CuryTaxTotal;
                orderHeaderObject.OrderDesc = quote.Subject;

                orderHeaderObject = orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Insert(orderHeaderObject);
                orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Current = orderHeaderObject;
                orderGraphObjet.Actions.PressSave();

                orderHeaderObject = orderGraphObjet.CurrentDocument.Current;

                foreach (CROpportunityProducts tran in QuoteList)
                {
                    SOLine transline = new SOLine(); //EMPTY DAC OBJECT

                    transline.OrderNbr = orderHeaderObject.OrderNbr;
                    transline.BranchID = orderHeaderObject.BranchID;
                    transline.InventoryID = tran.InventoryID;
                    transline.TranDesc = tran.Descr;
                    transline.UOM = tran.UOM;
                    transline.OrderQty = tran.Quantity;
                    transline.SiteID = tran.SiteID;
                    transline.CuryUnitPrice = tran.CuryUnitPrice;
                    transline.CuryExtPrice = tran.CuryExtPrice;

                    orderGraphObjet.Transactions.Insert(transline); //INSERT DAC INTO DATAVIEW

                    CROpportunityProductsExt xOppProductExt = PXCache<CROpportunityProducts>.GetExtension<CROpportunityProductsExt>(tran);
                    SOLineExt _soLext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(transline);   // GET DAC ENTENSION

                    _soLext.UsrXSeqID = xOppProductExt.UsrXSequenceID;
                    _soLext.UsrXGroupID = xOppProductExt.UsrXGroupID;
                    _soLext.UsrInternalRemk = xOppProductExt.UsrInternalRemk;   // ASSIGN CUSTOM FIELDS

                    orderGraphObjet.Transactions.Update(transline); // UPDATE DAC OBJECT IN DATAVIEW

                }
                orderGraphObjet.Actions.PressSave();
                var_orderCreated = true;

            //if (orderGraphObjet != null && orderHeaderObject != null)
            if (var_orderCreated)
            {
                orderGraphObjet.Document.Current = orderHeaderObject; // HERE I AM GETTING THE OrderType as well as OrderNbr to open the Document.

                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(orderGraphObjet, "Document") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
            }
     }

            #endregion


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the redirection is in the PXLongOperation. A PXLongOperation starts a separate thread that is not related with the UI. In order to solve this you can use the PXCustomInfo structure to talk back with the UI thread after the long operation finishes and thus be able to redirect to the so screen.

```
// PXCustomInfoDefinition
public sealed class SORedirectionCustomInfo: IPXCustomInfo
{
    private PXGraph _OrderGraph;
    public SORedirectionCustomInfo(PXGraph orderGraph)
    {
        _OrderGraph = orderGraph;
    }

    public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph)
    {
        if (status == PXLongRunStatus.Completed && graph is <YourQuoteGraphType>)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(orderGraphObjet, "Document") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
        }
    }
}

// Long Operation Method
public virtual void CreateSalesOrderMethod(CRQuote quote, List<CROpportunityProducts> QuoteList)
{
    // Your code to create SO....
    if (var_orderCreated)
    {
        PXLongOperation.SetCustomInfo(new SORedirectionCustomInfo(orderGraphObjet));
    }
}
```

This should be able to redirect successfully once the long operation is completed and the order is created.

Comment: Hi Jean, I have tried your method, but no luck. can you let me know exactly where i need to define the CustomInfo, right now I have defined it below  #endregion tag of my code.
but there I am not getting any reference of orderGraphObject for throwing PXRedirectRequiredException, I have defined the following line: "SOOrderEntry orderGraphObjet = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();" after 
private PXGraph _OrderGraph; to get the orderGraphObject . is that correct..? Please Suggest. Thanks